# Pop up message to display for few seconds in selenium

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, selenium

I am running a selenium script using Java. The functionality of the code is to open a Google web page and exit the browser. 
After exiting the browser i need a pop up message to be displayed saying "Code executed" and fade away in couple of seconds.
I believe there is an way to display a message either by using JQuery or Javascript but i do not know how to inject that JQuery/Javascript method into my script.
Here's my code:

public class test1 {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://google.com");

    driver.quit();
    //I need a method here to display a pop up msg and fade away
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `JavascriptExecutor` to execute javascript like so: `JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript(YOUR SCRIPT HERE);`. Just search Stackoverflow and Google for examples of `JavascriptExecutor`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line where ever you want to display the popup box.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Welcome please look in to the process");
```

plese go through https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Regards,

BK